# Customizing Web Parts - hiding prop in edit mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Update:

```
private string _catalogIconImageUrl = "http://hostname/images/favicon.ico";

 [WebBrowsableAttribute(false),
    Category("HIDDEN"),
    Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User),
    WebDisplayName("Catalog Icon Image url"),
    WebDescription("Something")]
    public string CatalogIconImageUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return _catalogIconImageUrl;
        }
        set
        {
            _catalogIconImageUrl = value;
        }
    }
```

with the above code, it does not show the image and also when i click on edit the webpart i still able to see the catalogIconImageUrl prop in edit mode

**Update end**

I've declared the property CatalogIconImageURL in the `.Webpart` file as follows:-

```
</property>    
<property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string">images/company/companylogo.jpg</property>    //sample path...
</properties>
```

if I click on the Advanced Web Part Gallery as shown below in the screen shot, i able to see that property in `editable` so my question is, is there a way i can hide this property when user edit the web part? `"Catalog Icon Image URL"`

[image]

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311196/hiding-default-properties-for-a-custom-visual-web-part

Comment: I've just tested it and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `WebBrowseable` or `Browseable` attribute to `false`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webbrowsableattribute.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.browsable.aspx

Update:

It is also marked as virtual. This property is a OOTB property in WEb Part class. See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.catalogiconimageurl.aspx

You should override this property and then set the above attribute to `false`

```
     /// <summary>
            /// Catalog Icon
            /// </summary>
            [Category("Properties")]
            [DefaultValue("")]
            [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
            [WebDisplayName("Catalog icon image URL:")]
            [WebDescription("Enter the WebPart title.")]
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "CatalogIconImageUrl")]
            [WebBrowsable(false)]
            public override string CatalogIconImageUrl
            {
}
```

Comment: okay so if i use `browsable` and still showing the catalog icon image url when i edit the webpart...

Comment: You don't have to use, you have to set both attribute to false. Can you show us updated code

Comment: Are you even able to compile this code? WebBrowsableAttribute(false) is wrong, it should be WebBrowsable(false)

Comment: i able to compile with `WebBrowsableAttribute(false)` and also able to compile with `WebBrowsable(false) ` even if i have WebBrowsable(false) i still able to view the prop in edit mode.

Comment: it did not hide the prop and yes i am using override

Comment: Did you get this working in the ens for hiding individual properties?